# Git to Mercurial convert commit message reference

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I was thinking I might convert a work mercurial repository to a git one. I have seen many things about this, but one of the ones I want to know about the most at the moment is if there is a conversion method that also converts revision references in commit messages as well so messages like "Copied file from rev 2345a88d7" will still point to the right revision in the git version?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. All `git` <-> `hg` converters I know can **add** reference to commit IDs in the original repo but none **modifies** existing commit messages.

Comment: @phd: well, if you write your own tool to do the conversion, it's certainly *possible* since you can make sure you convert the earlier Mercurial commit first, and keep a mapping table. The *really* hard part is figuring out that some commit message should be modified. :-)